# Can't figure out how to make the correct repository method I need

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, relation

I am trying to make a QueryBuilder with a join between my entity Product and my entity Store. I'd like to display all products that are related to OneStore. They have a many-to-many relation. I can't figure out how to get the ID's. Welp please. Thanks in advance!

here's a screenshot of my product_store table :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LYnu.jpg

So if I'm clear enough and my english legit, you understood that I'd like to display only the product that are related to one store id.

Let's make an example. If I'm on the /store/detail/{1} page, I'd like to display product id 1,3,6,8,10,13 since they are related to store.id = 1.

So I updated as I have been advised, but it's not working, and I don't get what is wrong. Where am I mistaking? (controller updated)

Here's the error I get : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggCgk.jpg

----------------------my repository function -----------------------------

```php
public function getProductsForStore($sid)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->join('s.product', 'p')
            ->addSelect('p')
            ->andWhere('s.id = :sid')
            ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC')
            ->setParameter('sid', $sid)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

$produt in store entity :

```php
/**
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="store")
     * * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_store",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $product;
```

$store in product entity :

```php
/**
     * * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Store", inversedBy="product")
     * * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_store",
     *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="store_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $store;
```

my controller function :

```php
/**
     * @Route("stores/detail/{id}", name="detail_store"))
     */
    public function getOneStore(StoreRepository $repository, Store $store): Response
    {
        $store = $repository->findOneBy(array(
            'id' => $store->getId(),
        ));
        $products_store = $repository->getProductsForStore(':id');

        return $this->render('store.html.twig', array(
            'store' => $store,
            'product' => $products_store,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Can you place part of your Store and Product entities that will show the ManyToMany relation to eachother?

Comment: Hello there, thanks for the answer! I updated it with my controller function, and my entities!

Answer (score 0):

I do wonder why you make a custom query if you want to get all products from one store.

When you made your ManyToMany relation (with maker bundle hopefully), you should also have added in `Store` entity a getter (`$store->getProducts()`) to get all products of said store.

Anyway, here is your query...

```
public function getAllProductsFromOneStore(Store $store) {
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('store');

    $qb->addSelect('product')
       ->join('store.product', 'product')
       ->andWhere('store.id = :storeId')
       ->setParameters(array(
           'storeId'=>$store->getId();
       ));

    return $qb->getQuery->getResult();
}
```

The above query should return all products from one store.
Also, never use `where()`, always `andWhere()`. [Read more about it here.](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/and-where-or-where)

**[EDIT]**

In response to your edit. As Frank B said, you can do better.
First, as I said, you don't need a custom query.
Instead, make a getter in `Store` and `Product` entity.

<kbd>**src/Entity/Store.php**</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Store {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="stores")
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->products=new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * GETTER
     * 
     * @return Collection|Product[]
     */
    public function getProducts(): Collection {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * ADD A PRODUCT TO A STORE
     */
    public function addProduct(Product $product): self {
        if(!$this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products[]=$product;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * REMOVE A PRODUCT FROM A STORE
     */
    public function removeProduct(Product $product): self {
        if($this->products->contains($product)) {
            $this->products->removeElement($product);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

<kbd>**src/Entity/Product.php**</kbd>

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Product {
    private $stores;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->stores=new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * GETTER
     * 
     * @return Collection|Store[]
     */
    public function getStores(): Collection {
        return $this->stores;
    }
    /**
     * ADD A STORE TO A PRODUCT
     */
    public function addStore(Store $store): self {
        if(!$this->stores->contains($store)) {
            $this->stores[]=$store;
            $store->addProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * REMOVE A STORE FROM A PRODUCT
     */
    public function removeStore(Store $store): self {
        if($this->stores->contains($store)) {
            $this->stores->removeElement($store);
            $store->removeProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now in your controller, all you have to do is to call your getter.
Doctrine will handle the query for you :

```
/**
 * @Route("stores/store-{id}", name="index_store"))
 */
public function index(Store $store): Response {
    $products=$store->getProducts();

    return $this->render('store.html.twig', array(
        'store'=>$store,
        'products'=>$products,
    ));
}
```

And then in your twig view :

```
{% for product in store.products %}
    // Your code here
{% endfor %}
```

And that is it. Once you have your getter in your entities, you don't need a custom query.

Take note that you can do the same with `Product` (`$product->getStores()`) to know in which store you can find your product.

Comment: and what is the correct way to use the $store->getProducts() in my controller?

Comment: Update your question with your entities `Store` and `Product` as asked by Frank B, and also add your controller function. We can't help you that much without seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't update untill now @salfysox. Just completed my answer. As I thought, you don't need a custom query. Check the part after **EDIT**

Answer (score 0):

you can better call your properties $stores and $products instead of the singular version to make clear that we talk about an array or collection with possible multiple stores or products. You dont really need the 2nd - 4th rule of your annotations. Just

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="store")
 */
```

and

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Store", inversedBy="product")
 */
```

will do. It tells us that you use a bidirectional ManyToMany relation. Both Store and Product entities hold a list of the opposite enitity. Therefor you can query Stores with a collection of Products or Products with a collection of Stores.

> and what is the correct way to use the $store->getProducts() in my controller?

So exchange store for product and vica versa in the first answer:

```
    public function getStore($sid)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->join('s.product', 'p')
            ->addSelect('p')
            ->andWhere('s.id = :sid')
            ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC')
            ->setParameter('sid', $sid);
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="store_show", methods={"GET"})
     */

    public function show($id): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->getRepository('App:Store')->getStore($id);

        if(null === $store) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Store not found.');
        }

        return $this->render('store/show.html.twig', [
            'store' => $store,
        ]);
    }
```

Twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Store{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ store.name }}</h1>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ProductId</th>
                <th>ProductName</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for product in store.products %}  {# loop through all products in store #}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% else %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">no records found</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I updated my code and post taking into account what you've told me. Can you keep helping me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: extended my answer

Comment: It tells me "Notice: Undefined variable: sid" from the ->getStore($sid) in the controller..

Comment: So I guess I just gotta declare it just above in the controller and it'll make it?

Comment: I did  :   $sid = $repository->getStore(':id');    just above and it worked! yeaahhhhh thanks a lot Frank! You're the best!

Comment: Haha there always better ones but thanks a lot and i removed the s from sid now.